# Handling RabbitMQ node failures in a cluster in order to continue publishing and consuming

Tags: rabbitmq

I would like to create a cluster for high availability and put a load balancer front of this cluster. In our configuration, we would like to create exchanges and queues manually, so one exchanges and queues are created, no client should make a call to redeclare them. I am using direct exchange with a routing key so its possible to route the messages into different queues on different nodes. However, I have some issues with clustering and queues.

As far as I read in the RabbitMQ documentation a queue is specific to the node it was created on. Moreover, we can only one queue with the same name in a cluster which should be alive in the time of publish/consume operations. If the node dies then the queue on that node will be gone and messages may not be recovered (depends on the configuration of course). So, even if I route the same message to different queues in different nodes, still I have to figure out how to use them in order to continue consuming messages.

I wonder if it is possible to handle this failover scenario without using mirrored queues. Say I would like switch to a new node in case of a failure and continue to consume from the same queue. Because publisher is just using routing key and these messages can go into more than one queue, same situation is not possible for the consumers.

In short, what can I to cope with the failures in an environment explained in the first paragraph. Queue mirroring is the best approach with a performance penalty in the cluster or a more practical solution exists?

Answer (score 0):

Data replication (mirrored queues in RabbitMQ) is a standard approach to achieve high availability. I suggest to use those. If you don't replicate your data, you will lose it.

If you are worried about performance - RabbitMQ does not scale well.
The only way I know to improve performance is just to make your nodes bigger or create second cluster. Adding nodes to cluster does not really improve things. Also if you are planning to use TLS it will decrease throughput significantly as well. If you have high throughput requirement +HA I'd consider Apache Kafka.

If your use case allows not to care about HA, then just re-declare queues/exchanges whenever your consumers/publishers connect to the broker, which is absolutely fine. When you declare queue that's already exists nothing wrong will happen, queue won't be purged etc, same with exchange.

Also, check out [RabbitMQ sharding plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding), maybe that will do for your usecase.

Comment: So redeclaring an existing exchange/queue (if it is not dutable) in the node is idempotent and whenever a new connection is established redeclaration can be done, right? Is that your suggestion?

Comment: @Deniz yes just declare queues/exchanges that your client needs. Publisher just needs to declare exchange. Consumer should declare exchange and queue

Comment: Thanks for the tips Alex. I think its not possible to redeclare durable queues so your solution is valid for nondurable queues right?

Comment: @Deniz yes that's right. You can still issue `queue.declare` command for durable queue, you'll just get error response which is fine. You just make sure queue is there